# Grouping Lists into specific groups

Tags: python, python-3.x, grouping, listings

I'm wondering if it is possible to convert the listings into a specific groups to which I could place them in a table format later on.

This is the output that I needed to group, I converted them into a list so that I could easily divide them in table manner.

```
f=open("sample1.txt", "r")
f.read()
```

Here's the output:

```
'0245984300999992018010100004+14650+121050FM-12+004699999V0203001N00101090001CN008000199+02141+01971101171ADDAY141021AY241021GA1021+006001081GA2061+090001021GE19MSL   +99999+99999GF106991021999006001999999KA1120N+02111MD1210141+9999MW1051REMSYN10498430 31558 63001 10214 20197 40117 52014 70544 82108 333 20211 55062 56999 59012 82820 86280 555 60973=\n'
```

Here's what I have done already. I have managed to change it into a list which resulted in this output:

```
with open('sample1.txt', 'r') as file:
data = file.read().replace('\n', '')
print (list(data))
```

The Output:

['0', '2', '4', '5', '9', '8', '4', '3', '0', '0', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '2', '0', '1', '8', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '4', '+', '1', '4', '6', '5', '0', '+', '1', '2', '1', '0', '5', '0', 'F', 'M', '-', '1', '2', '+', '0', '0', '4', '6', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', 'V', '0', '2', '0', '3', '0', '0', '1', 'N', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '9', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'C', 'N', '0', '0', '8', '0', '0', '0', '1', '9', '9', '+', '0', '2', '1', '4', '1', '+', '0', '1', '9', '7', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '7', '1', 'A', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'Y', '1', '4', '1', '0', '2', '1', 'A', 'Y', '2', '4', '1', '0', '2', '1', 'G', 'A', '1', '0', '2', '1', '+', '0', '0', '6', '0', '0', '1', '0', '8', '1', 'G', 'A', '2', '0', '6', '1', '+', '0', '9', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '2', '1', 'G', 'E', '1', '9', 'M', 'S', 'L', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '+', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', 'G', 'F', '1', '0', '6', '9', '9', '1', '0', '2', '1', '9', '9', '9', '0', '0', '6', '0', '0', '1', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', 'K', 'A', '1', '1', '2', '0', 'N', '+', '0', '2', '1', '1', '1', 'M', 'D', '1', '2', '1', '0', '1', '4', '1', '+', '9', '9', '9', '9', 'M', 'W', '1', '0', '5', '1', 'R', 'E', 'M', 'S', 'Y', 'N', '1', '0', '4', '9', '8', '4', '3', '0', ' ', '3', '1', '5', '5', '8', ' ', '6', '3', '0', '0', '1', ' ', '1', '0', '2', '1', '4', ' ', '2', '0', '1', '9', '7', ' ', '4', '0', '1', '1', '7', ' ', '5', '2', '0', '1', '4', ' ', '7', '0', '5', '4', '4', ' ', '8', '2', '1', '0', '8', ' ', '3', '3', '3', ' ', '2', '0', '2', '1', '1', ' ', '5', '5', '0', '6', '2', ' ', '5', '6', '9', '9', '9', ' ', '5', '9', '0', '1', '2', ' ', '8', '2', '8', '2', '0', ' ', '8', '6', '2', '8', '0', ' ', '5', '5', '5', ' ', '6', '0', '9', '7', '3', '=']

My goal is to group them into something like these:

```
0245,984300,99999,2018,01,01,0000,4,+1....
```

The number of digits belonging to each column is predetermined, for example there are always 4 digits for the first column and 6 for the second, and so on.

I was thinking of concatenating them. But I'm not sure if it would be possible.

Comment: Hi! So there's a specific number of digits that were assigned for each and every group. like for the first group there would always be 4 digits for it, and the second one would always contain 6 digits, and 4 digits for the third and so on...

Comment: So you can iterate over the list you have generated and write a logic according to the pattern of each group and simple concatenation will work. The list contains all characters, so concatenation is not at all a problem.

Comment: so, How do you split a list into group? Is there any logic, behind this?

Comment: @KrishnaSantos your third group has 5 digits

Comment: well the logic behind this is that this is a weather data, hence every code / group would have a corresponding meaning to it. @VJAYSLN

Comment: @igorkf ah yes! I do have 5 digits for my third group sorry for the mistake !

Comment: Are you sure that the string will be the exactly same length every time? Which parts of it would be variable length if no?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `operator.itemgetter`

```
from operator import itemgetter

g = itemgetter(slice(0, 4), slice(4, 10))
with open('sample1.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(g(line))
```

Or even better you can make the slices dynamically using zip and `itertools.accumulate`:

```
indexes = [4, 6, ...]
g = itemgetter(*map(slice, *map(accumulate, zip([0]+indexes, indexes))))
```

Then proceed as before

Comment: Hi! I have tried this one, but the output became like this: ('0245', '843009') instead of having  ('0245', '984300'). it's as if the second group went in reverse order.

Comment: Oops I corrected. It was supposed to be 4-10 not 5-11. Slices exclude the upper bound.

Comment: Added a better option as well

Comment: Hi! @Jab i was wondering whenever I tried of putting this into a table. It always says that there is a "None" value.

Comment: Kudos on the idea of using the `itemgetter()` & `slice()` together like that (in the first snippet) — very clever and not at all obvious from the documentation that it's possible.

Comment: Much appreciated! Honored to get the kudos from you as well!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend naming everything if you actually want to use this data, and double checking that all the lengths make sense. So to start you do

```
with open('sample1.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().rstrip('\n"')
    first, second, *rest = data.split()

    if len(first) != 163:
        raise ValueError(f"The first part should be 163 characters long, but it's {len(first)}")
    if len(second) != 163:
        raise ValueError(f"The second part should be  characters long, but it's {len(first)}")
```

So now you have 3 variables

- `first` is `"0245984300999992018010100004+14650+121050FM-12+004699999V0203001N00101090001CN008000199+02141+01971101171ADDAY141021AY241021GA1021+006001081GA2061+090001021GE19MSL"`
- `second` is `"+99999+99999GF106991021999006001999999KA1120N+02111MD1210141+9999MW1051REMSYN10498430"`
- `rest` is `['31558', '63001', '10214', '20197', '40117', '52014', '70544', '82108', '333', '20211', '55062', '56999', '59012', '82820', '86280', '555', '60973']`

And then repeat that idea

```
date, whatever, whatever2, whatever3 = first.split('+')
```

and then for parsing the first part I would just have a list like

```
something = date[0:4]
something_else = date[4:10]
third_thing = date[10:15]
year = [15:19]
month = [19:21]
day = [21:23]
```

and so on. And then you can use all these variables in the code that analyzes them.

If this is some sort of standard, you should look for a library that parses strings like that or write one yourself.

Obviously name the variables better

Comment: Hi! So I have tried running it. and this result to an error : ValueError: The second part should be  characters long, but it's 163

Comment: You're supposed to read and understand what I'm trying to tell you to do, not run the code as it is. I wrote that in a real hurry, it's just a general guide for how you should approach the problem.

Comment: I didn't measure how long the second string should be, find out it's `len` and change the second `163` to whatever is the right value

Comment: Also, as I said, are you sure this isn't a standard or something someone else has already written a library for?