# Removing ' and () in the table

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

I'm wondering if it is possible to remove the ' and () symbol in the data using a python code. The code that I have used in the first part of the code goes like this:

For the first part, I was tasked to get some of the information in this line of data.

> '0245984300999992018010100004+14650+121050FM-12+004699999V0203001N00101090001CN008000199+02141+01971101171ADDAY141021AY241021GA1021+006001081GA2061+090001021GE19MSL   +99999+99999GF106991021999006001999999KA1120N+02111MD1210141+9999MW1051REMSYN10498430 31558 63001 10214 20197 40117 52014 70544 82108 333 20211 55062 56999 59012 82820 86280 555 60973=\n'

The original set of data came from the 984300-99999-2018.txt which consists of data that looks like this:

> 0245984300999992018010100004+14650+121050FM-12+004699999V0203001N00101090001CN008000199+02141+01971101171ADDAY141021AY241021GA1021+006001081GA2061+090001021GE19MSL   +99999+99999GF106991021999006001999999KA1120N+02111MD1210141+9999MW1051REMSYN10498430 31558 63001 10214 20197 40117 52014 70544 82108 333 20211 55062 56999 59012 82820 86280 555 60973=
>   0223984300999992018010103004+14650+121050FM-12+004699999V0200201N002010240019N008000199+02721+01981101171ADDAY141021AY241021GA1031+006001061GA2061+024001031GE19MSL   +99999+99999GF106991031999006001999999MD1490001+9999MW1051REMSYN07698430 31558 60202 10272 20198 40117 58000 70544 83870 333 56999 83620 86358=EQDQ018     3APCTEN
>   0204984300999992018010106004+14650+121050FM-12+004699999V0200701N003010240019N008000199+02821+02031100981ADDAY141021AY241021GA1031+006001061GA2061+024001031GE19MSL   +99999+99999GF106991031999006001999999MD1710191+9999MW1051REMSYN07698430 31558 60703 10282 20203 40098 57019 70544 83870 333 56999 83620 86358=
>   0204984300999992018010109004+14650+121050FM-12+004699999V0200601N002010240019N008000199+02831+01961100811ADDAY141021AY241021GA1021+006001061GA2071+024001031GE19MSL   +99999+99999GF107991021999006001999999MD1310171+9999MW1051REMSYN07698430 31558 70602 10283 20196 40081 53017 70544 82470 333 56999 82620 87358=

etc... this contains larger amount of data but always in the same format, Which is why I used the itemgetter in order to just slice the data that I needed for the file:

```
from operator import itemgetter

g = itemgetter(#STATION DESCRIPTION
               slice(15, 19), slice(19, 21), slice(21, 23), slice(23, 27),
                #WIND
                slice(60,63), slice(63,64), slice(64,65), slice(65,69), slice(69,70),
               #AIR TEMPERATURE
               slice(87,92), slice(92,93), slice(93,98), slice(98,99),
               #ATMOSPHERIC PRESSURE
               slice(99,104), slice(104,105))


with open('sample1.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(g(line))
f.close()
```

which resulted to this result:

> ('2018', '01', '01', '0000', '300', '1', 'N', '0010', '1', '+0214', '1', '+0197', '1', '10117', '1')

that's where the (' came from which I want to remove because everytime I put it into the csv file it would always looks like this:
[image: result in csv format]

My code for the csv file goes like this:

```
import unicodecsv as csv
f = open("ogimet.csv", "wb")

writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter =",",quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
writer.writerows([["YEAR", "MONTH", "DAY", "TIME",
                   "WIND DIRECTION", "WIND DIRECTION QUALITY", "WIND TYPE","WIND SPEED", "WIND SPEED QUALITY",
                   "AIR TEMPERATURE", "AIR TEMPERATURE QUALITY",
                   "DEW POINT TEMPERATURE", "DEW POINT TEMPERATURE QUALITY",
                   "SEA PRESSURE", "SEA LEVEL PRESSURE QUALITY"], [(g(line))]])
f.close()
```

```
import csv

with open('ogimet.csv', 'w') as f:
    for row in data:
        f.write(','.join(row))
        f.write('\n')
```

Comment: Please look into [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) or, even better, [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) instead of reinventing the wheel with `f.write(','.join(row))` and `f.write('\n')`.

Comment: Why are you using itemgetter? Using csv library or accessing the file line by line with open() is easier.

Comment: Hi! i only needed some parts of the bulk data which is why I used the itemgetter @daniboy000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it based on the update you made to your question. The bulk data is read now from a file and written directly to the output CSV file.

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter


bulkdata_filepath = r'984300-99999-2018.txt'
csv_filepath = r'ogimet.csv'
header = ("YEAR", "MONTH", "DAY", "TIME",
          "WIND DIRECTION", "WIND DIRECTION QUALITY", "WIND TYPE","WIND SPEED",
            "WIND SPEED QUALITY",
          "AIR TEMPERATURE", "AIR TEMPERATURE QUALITY",
          "DEW POINT TEMPERATURE", "DEW POINT TEMPERATURE QUALITY",
          "SEA PRESSURE", "SEA LEVEL PRESSURE QUALITY")

g = itemgetter(#STATION DESCRIPTION
               slice(15, 19), slice(19, 21), slice(21, 23), slice(23, 27),
               #WIND
               slice(60,63), slice(63,64), slice(64,65), slice(65,69), slice(69,70),
               #AIR TEMPERATURE
               slice(87,92), slice(92,93), slice(93,98), slice(98,99),
               #ATMOSPHERIC PRESSURE
               slice(99,104), slice(104,105))

with open(bulkdata_filepath, 'r') as bulkdata, \
     open(csv_filepath, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(g(row) for row in bulkdata)

print('done')
```

Contents of `ogimet.csv` file created:

```
YEAR,MONTH,DAY,TIME,WIND DIRECTION,WIND DIRECTION QUALITY,WIND TYPE,WIND SPEED,WIND SPEED QUALITY,AIR TEMPERATURE,AIR TEMPERATURE QUALITY,DEW POINT TEMPERATURE,DEW POINT TEMPERATURE QUALITY,SEA PRESSURE,SEA LEVEL PRESSURE QUALITY
2018,01,01,0000,300,1,N,0010,1,+0214,1,+0197,1,10117,1
2018,01,01,0300,020,1,N,0020,1,+0272,1,+0198,1,10117,1
2018,01,01,0600,070,1,N,0030,1,+0282,1,+0203,1,10098,1
2018,01,01,0900,060,1,N,0020,1,+0283,1,+0196,1,10081,1
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for this, this really helps me out! Additional if you don't mind, for the bulk_data in the very first part if I wanted to use a specific text file containing the data, what code can I use to replace it? instead of putting all the numbers there? thank you!

Comment: @Krishna: Do you mean you want to read the bulk data from a file instead of the `sample1.txt` in your question? If so, please edit your question and add some sample bulk data to it (i.e. more than one line).

Comment: yes, sir. `sample1.txt` is only one line part from a bigger data, and i was only testing on how it would work on that one line. there is another txt.file in which contains all of the data and follows the same format with the `sample1.txt`

Comment: I was thinking of using `bulk_data = (r"C:\Users\Krishna\Desktop\!Meteo\Meteo 221 - PhyMet Lab\Assignment\Ogimet\984300-99999-2018.txt")` where in `984300-99999-2018.txt` is the text file for the main bulk data

Comment: @Krishna: That's good to hear. BTW, admire your `itemgetter` + `slice` technique—very "python-esque" Will have to remember it.

Comment: Think I now know where you got the [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58835847/355230).

Answer (score -1):

- think you are getting tuple as output. So rather than passing `(g(line))`
  pass it with indexes as `(g(line))[0], (g(line))[1], etc` for removing ' You should type convert the elements as int((g(line))[0]) for its respective representation.